# How to encrypt messages using TLS encryption and send to sys logger?

Tags: linux, encryption, ssl, logger

I am using following `logger` command to send message to `/var/log/message`.

```
logger -n 10.102.5.19 "system shutdown"
```

my question is, how to encrypt the message("system shutdown") using TLS encryption. I am having certificate file(.cer), jks file(.jks) and pem file(.pem) files. I have to make use these file to send encrypted message to remote server(10.102.5.19).

Please help me in understanding how to make use of these files with Unix commands for encryption.

Comment: The first answer to "logger tls" in Google is [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091659/how-to-send-tls-syslog-message-via-logger-command) on another SE site.

Comment: Ok @garethTheRed